does anyone know how to program browser icons in html(5)
I am working on a website and I want a browser icon, I typed the code
<link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" href="Screenshot 2024-03-13 202924.jpeg">

I don't know why it doesn't work.

Does this answer your question? How to add a browser tab icon (favicon) for a website?

You need to convert your icon image to a .ico file most of the time I use the favicon.io website to achieve all the right format https://favicon.io/favicon-converter

BTW you don`t have too answer this because the code I needed is not needed anymore because I abonded the website
